# SQL XML: Group field elements into one row

Tags: sql, xml, xquery

The actual xml format of data to extract is:

```
<report>
  <data>
    <row>
      <field id="-2">Sterling, Bruce</field>
      <field id="18">Austin, TX</field>
      <field id="636">123456</field>
    </row>
```

===========

```
declare @DocHandle int
declare @XMLDoc nvarchar (MAX)
declare @xml XML

SELECT @xml = XMLData FROM CompanyXML

SELECT
   Tab.Col.value('.[@id="-2"]', 'varchar(50)') AS FullName,
   Tab.Col.value('.[@id="18"]', 'varchar(50)') AS Location,
   Tab.Col.value('.[@id="636"]', 'varchar(50)') AS EmployeeNbr

FROM @xml.nodes('report/data/row/field') Tab(Col)
```

The results are one row for FullName of Bruce Sterling with NULLS in the other columns, then another row for Location of Brownsville, TX, then another row for EmployeeNbr of 123456.

But instead of key pairs rows, I need just one row for that person with relevant info.

That is, one row for:  FullName, Location, and EmployeeNbr.

I've tried CROSS APPLY and TOP but without success.  What is the correct XQUERY to get the one row for that person and relevant info?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this OPENXML works.  It was a matter of going up a level in the XPATH for OPENXML and down a level for the WITH section.  Thanks to a friend who helped me.

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM CompanyXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'report/data/row',2)
WITH
(
   FullName [varchar](50) './field[@id="-2"]',
   Location [varchar](50) './field[@id="18"]',
   EmployeeNbr [varchar](50) './field[@id="636"]'
)


EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```